# send command over BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, android-bluetooth, gatt

I am trying to connect to BC127 using BLE profile from my android phone. I am able to search BLE device But I am not sure how I can retrieve the services available on remote BLE device.I saw several example but all contains the UUID of service. How can I know the UUID of service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you search BLE device,

you can follow Android developer "http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/project.html" to connect device.

In "BluetoothLeService.java", you can get service when you connect to device successfully by `gatt.discoverServices()` (You can run that in `onConnectionStateChange`).

It will trigger `onServicesDiscovered()`;

In `onServicesDiscovered()`, try `gatt.getServices()` to get list of services, and in every service try `service.getCharacteristics()` to get list of Characteristics, and in every Characteristics, try `characteristics.getDescriptors()` to get descriptor.

In each Service, Characteristics and descriptor,  use `getUUID()` to get UUID information.

Hope its useful for you

Thanks,
Devin.

Comment: Thank you Devin. Thats what I did But in logcat I am getting "Client registerd, waiting for callback" I searched for this and got that we have to create new thread for ConnectGatt(). I did that also But I dont know whats wrong

Comment: These are the steps I am following 1. Search for BLE device 2. Connect using ConnectGatt() 3. Waiting for callback to call OnConnectionStateChanged() where I called gatt.getServices() to explore the services on remote device.